# Saucelabs tests block on browser allow dialog

Tags: selenium, saucelabs

My web app uses IndexedDB and I'm testing on SauceLabs. Some months back my tests ran but now they block on a browser dialog that says "http://gbserver3.cs.unc.edu/" wants to: store files on this device", with an Allow button.

This is Win7 and Chrome or Firefox. Likely others too.

How can I dismiss or prevent this dialog?

**Update**: I have discovered that if I don't ask for quota I don't get the popup and my tests succeed. I'd still like to learn how to get rid of that dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we are using [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/) in our project and we were facing the same issue.

What actually did the trick was using `--unlimited-storage` switch when launching the browser.

(List of other command line switches for Chromium can be found [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#unlimited-storage))